# How to properly use formik.values in map for typescript?

Tags: typescript, formik

I met a error on using a useFormik for typescript, can anybody help? Thanks a lot.

In line `const value = formik.values[field.name];` , I am getting this error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; description: string; color: string; }'.

```
const fields = [
  {name: 'name', label: 'GENERAL.NAME'},
  {name: 'description', label: 'GENERAL.DESC'},
  {name: 'color', label: 'GENERAL.COLOR'}
];

export const Create: React.FC = () => {
  const {loading} = useSelector<RootState>(
    (state) => state.calendarReducer,
    shallowEqual
  ) as CalendarState;

  const formik = useFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: {name: '', description: '', color: Constants.COLORS.AppleRed},
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    }
  });

  return (
    <form className='form' onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      {fields.map((field, index) => {
        const value = formik.values[field.name];
        return (
          <div
            key={index}
            className='sm-6 md-4 lg-3 my-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'
          >
            <label className=''>
              <FormattedMessage id={field.label} />
            </label>
            <TextField
              disabled={loading}
              fullWidth={false}
              name={field.name}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              value={'xxxxxx'}
              variant='standard'
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </form>
  );
};
```

[the code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0yyQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `fields` as a literal value with a `const` assertion.

```
type Values = {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  color: string;
}
declare const values: Values;

const fields = [
  {name: 'name', label: 'GENERAL.NAME'},
  {name: 'description', label: 'GENERAL.DESC'},
  {name: 'color', label: 'GENERAL.COLOR'}
] as const;

fields.map((field) => values[field.name]); // no error
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! And can you share me more info why this work? I can't understand..

Comment: If you remove `as const` and hover over `fields` you will see that the type is `{ name: string; label: string; }[]`. However, with `as const`, TypeScript will be more specific about the type of the `name` and `label` values (try hovering with `as const`).